# creating a bootstrap-esque glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a glyphicon of sorts somewhere, but want to use my own image for it. I first looked into the bootstrap components, found a glyphicon, and checked out the CSS. This looked like the part that was relevant to what I wanted.

```
.glyphicon-user:before {
  content: "\e008";
}
```

I really don't know how to make sense of this. My final goal is to make something like `<span class="glyphicon my-glyphicon"></span>` and have my own image show up just like the bootstrap kinds.

How is this done?

Comment: Glyphicon is a font. The icons are not images. They used to be images in the previous version (2.3.2).

Comment: You'll have to create your custom icon as an SVG file, then you can use a tool like [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) to convert it into a font.

Comment: Do note that this only works for flat, single color icons. And http://icomoon.io is a great tool as well!

Comment: can they be a different color than black?